# Encoding into NSValue array of structs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, opengl-es

Im trying to encode into a NSValue an multidimensional array of structs.

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
} Vertex;

const Vertex Vertices[] = {
    // Front
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
(etc...)
```

I need to encode into a NSValue to store it in the object "Block".

This is what I do to store:

```
Block *newBlock = [[Block alloc] init];
newBlock.blockVertices = [NSValue value:&Vertices withObjCType:@encode(Vertex)];
```

And to get it back:

```
Vertex tempVertices[24];
[newBlock.blockVertices getValue:&tempVertices];
```

Everything seems to work fine, then I try to compare values like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
    NSLog(@"%f = %f", Vertices[i].Position[0], tempVertices[i].Position[0]);
    NSLog(@"%f = %f", Vertices[i].Position[1], tempVertices[i].Position[1]);
    NSLog(@"%f = %f", Vertices[i].Position[2], tempVertices[i].Position[2]);
    NSLog(@" ");
}
```

And I'm getting weird results, like:
-1.000000 = -1.998905

where could be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `@encode` how many `Vertex` structs are being encoded, for example:

```
[NSValue value:&Vertices withObjCType:@encode(Vertex[24])];
```